# How can I get the ratio of two audio signals in the frequencies domain?

Tags: java, signal-processing, fft

I need to compare two audio signals, signal1 and signal2. Signal1 is a white noise. Signal2 is the same signal of signal1, with a particular equalization for cutting or for attenuating some frequencies. 
How can I get the ratio of two audio signals in the frequencies domain? (e.g.: at the frequency of 100Hz, signal2 is attenuated by 50% compared to signal1).
I need this information to process a third signal by applying the same equalization applied to transform signal1 in signal2.

I used [this library](http://incanter.org/docs/parallelcolt/api/edu/emory/mathcs/jtransforms/fft/DoubleFFT_1D.html) to process my data and pass from the time domain to the frequencies domain. This code is the same for signal1 and signal2.

```
DoubleFFT_1D fft1 = new DoubleFFT_1D (FFT_SIZE);
double[] input1 = new double[FFT_SIZE];

double[] fftBuff1 = new double[FFT_SIZE * 2];


this.wavFileDoubleInputStreamMic.read(input1, 0, FFT_SIZE);


for (int i = 0; i < FFT_SIZE; i++){
    fftBuff1[2*i] = input1[i];
    fftBuff1[2*i+1] = 0;
}


fft1.complexForward(fftBuff1);
```

How can I use FFT results (from signal1 and signal2) to reach my goal?

Comment: Why do you need to do the same equalization for the third signal ?

Comment: I need to transform the third signal with the same equalization, with no a priori knowledge of the equalization itself. It's just an experiment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate the magnitude of each signal in the frequency domain to get the power spectrum estimate for each, and then do a divsion, i.e.

- get signal 1 and signal 2
- apply suitable window function to both signals (e.g. von Hann)
- apply FFT to windowed signals
- calculate magnitude of FFT output, `mag = sqrt(re*re+im*im)` - this gives a real-valued power spectrum
- divide power spectrum of signal 1 by power spectrum of signal 2 to get real-valued ratio versus frequency

To apply this correction to signal 3 you can use the [overlap-add](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93add_method) or [overlap-save](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93save_method) method - essentially you take the FFT of signal3, multiply each complex value by the real value obtained above, then use an inverse FFT to get back to the time domain. The only slight complication is the need to overlap successive sample windows and process this overlap correctly (see links to overlap-add/overlap-save methods above.)

Comment: Thank you, Paul. This is the solution which I consider correct. But now how can I process signal3? I can apply FFT(signal3), calculate magnitude of FFT output, use previously calculated ratios to transform the power spectrum of signal3. But then how can I revert the power spectrum to a signal in the time domain?

Comment: OK - I've added a further paragraph covering this now.

Comment: Thank you. So after calculating FFT(signal3) is not necessary to calculate the magniutude of the FFT output before transforming the signal with  calculated ratios. Right?

Comment: That's correct - you can just scale the complex values in the frequency domain.

Comment: Thank you, Paul! It seems like the solution works perfectly! I was going crazy because using realInverse(fftBuff, false); I got strange results. Then I used realInverse(fftBuff, true) (from documentation: if true then scaling is performed) and the results seem to be correct. What kind of "scaling" is that?

Comment: There are different conventions for the definitions of forward and inverse FFT, but there can be an implicit scaling factor of N in one direction or the other, or sometimes even a scaling factor of sqrt(N) in both directions.